# My login system doesn't work. It only accept one account. How can i get it to work?

Tags: python, authentication, file-handling, login-system

This is my code:

if login_system == "1":

```
        user = open("userAccount.txt","r")

        while not loggedIn:

            Username = input("Enter player 1 username")
            Password = input("Enter player 1 password")

            for row in user:
                #print("ROW:", row)
                field = row.split(",")
                ID = field[0]
                username = field[1]
                password = field[2]
                score = field[3]
                lastchar = len(score)- 1
                score = score[0:lastchar]

                if Username == username and Password == password:
                    print("Welcome to dice game" + Username)
                    x = 0
                    loggedIn = True
                    break   
            print("Not the correct username and password. Try again or create a new account")

        user.close()

    elif login_system == "2":
        x = 0

    else:
        print("INVALID! Please try again.")
```

This is what it produces:

```
Welcome to the dice game
Press 1 if you want to sign in or press 2 if you want to sign up1
Enter player 1 usernameabid
Enter player 1 passwordpassword1
Welcome to dice gameabid
Not the correct username and password. Try again or create a new account
Round 1
Player 1 score: 0
Player 2 score: 4
Player 2 wins
Round 2
Player 1 score: 16
Player 2 score: 18
Player 2 wins
Round 3
Player 1 score: 16
Player 2 score: 2
Player 1 wins
Round 4
Player 1 score: 23
Player 2 score: 18
Player 1 wins
Round 5
Player 1 score: 2
Player 2 score: 0
Player 1 wins
The final score
player 1 highscore is: 57
Player 2 highscore is: 42
Player 1 wins

Welcome to the dice game
Press 1 if you want to sign in or press 2 if you want to sign up1
Enter player 1 usernameadam
Enter player 1 passwordpassword2
Welcome to dice gameadam
Not the correct username and password. Try again or create a new account
```

I want both accounts from the database to work. How I use any account from the database to log in. Thanks for the help.

New code:

```
while x == 1:
        login_system = input("Press 1 if you want to sign in or press 2 if you want to sign up")

        if login_system == "1":

            user = open("userAccount.txt","r")

            while not loggedIn:

                Username = input("Enter player 1 username")
                Password = input("Enter player 1 password")

                for row in user:
                    #print("ROW:", row)
                    field = row.split(",")
                    ID = field[0]
                    username = field[1]
                    password = field[2]
                    score = field[3]
                    lastchar = len(score)- 1
                    score = score[0:lastchar]

                    if Username == username and Password == password:
                        print("Welcome to dice game" + Username)
                        x = 0
                        loggedIn = True
                        break   
                #print("Not the correct username and password. Try again or create a new account")

            user.close()

        elif login_system == "2":
            x = 0

        else:
            print("INVALID! Please try again.")
```

The code works but if i enter the wrong username and password multiple times and then type the correct username and password, it doesn't work.

```
Welcome to the dice game
Press 1 if you want to sign in or press 2 if you want to sign up1
Enter player 1 usernamesdas
Enter player 1 passworddvgdvg
Enter player 1 usernamevgfrgr
Enter player 1 passwordrggr
Enter player 1 usernameabid
Enter player 1 passwordpassword1
Enter player 1 usernameadam
Enter player 1 passwordpassword2
Enter player 1 username
Enter player 1 password
Enter player 1 username
```

Comment: Please format your code properly --- Python code requires correct indentation to work correctly. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: i formatted my code now.